# Error "_keys2 is not defined" when calling .getVue() in Testcafe

Tags: testcafe

I got an issue when I tried to call `.getValue()` of component in app with Vuetify. I have tried other components but the result was the same.
Can anyone let me know how to get through?

[Issue in GitHub](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/52)

### Environments

- Chrome 89.0.4389.128 / macOS 11.2.3
- node: v14.15.5
- yarn: 1.22.10
- testcafe: 1.14.0
- testcafe-vue-selectors:  3.1.0
- vuetify: 2.4.2

### Test Codes

```js
const transfersTable = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data-table');
await t.hover(transfersTable); // OK

const transfersTableValues = await transfersTable.getVue(); // NOT OK
console.log(transfersTableValues);
```

[image]

### Results

```sh
  1) An error occurred in getVue code:

      ReferenceError: _keys2 is not defined

      Browser: Chrome 89.0.4389.128 / macOS 11.2.3

         20 |    .click(proceedButton);
         21 |
         22 |  const transfersTable = VueSelector('Transfer SingleAccountStatus v-data');
         23 |  await t.hover(transfersTable);
         24 |
       > 25 |  const transfersTableValues = await transfersTable.getVue();
         26 |  console.log(transfersTableValues);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. Please track the following thread:

["babel-core" should be included in package · Issue #51 · DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors (github.com)](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-vue-selectors/issues/51)

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer! Definitely I did not check for a while. I will try the fixed version :)